# How to get argv[0] in bpftrace?

Tags: ebpf

I have this rather simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bpftrace
tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_exec*
{
    @start[pid] = nsecs;
    printf("START;%-6d;", pid);
    join(args->argv);
}
tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_exit*
{
    $from = @start[pid];
    $until = nsecs;
    printf("STOP;%-5d;%-16d\n", pid, $until-$from);
}
```

I'd much rather have it print `args->argv[0]` instead of printing the often multi-line `join(args->argv)`.

Problem is that `printf("START;%-6d;%s", pid, args->argv[0]);` doesn't work:

```
/tmp/foo.bt:5:5-48: ERROR: printf: %s specifier expects a value of type string (integer supplied)
    printf("START;%-6d;%s", pid, args->argv[0]);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

pretty sure `args->argv` is a string array, so this kind of surprises me. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `str(args->argv[0])` as the last argument to `printf` should work. Without `str`, the expression refers to the pointer (address) itself, rather than the string it points to.